# I want make the same text of box1 appear in each line of box2

Tags: javascript, html

I want make the same text of text1 appear in each line of text2

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#btn").click(function(){
                var text1 = $('#text1').val();
                var text2 = $('#text2').val();
                $('#text3').val(text2+text1);
            });

    </script>
```

Comment: Please provide HTML and sample which you will input in both textboxes

Comment: Posted solution, try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
        var box1 = $('#box1').val();
        var box2 = $('#box2').val();
        let box3val = '';
        let boxVals = box2.split('\n');
        boxVals.forEach(function (x) {
            box3val += (x + ' '+ box1) + '\n';
        });
        $('#box3').val(box3val);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use textarea for box2 and try this code:

```js
let box1 = $('#box1').val();
let box2 = $('#box2').val().split('\n');
let text = ''
box2.forEach(i => {
  text += `${box1} ${i}, `
})
$('#box3').val(text);
```